# Function Template Specialization Syntax aggregating templated types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, function-templates

With respect to function template specialization, I would like help with a bit of syntax.  The following is a simplified scenario:

Base header:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T* t) { TRACE("Default Foo impl"); }  // <-- default implementation

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    explicit Base()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "T must derive from Base");
        Foo(static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
};
```

Derived_X header:

```
struct Derived_X : public Base<Derived_X>
{
    explicit Derived_X() : Base<Derived_X> { } { }
};

// no specialization will be implemented --> using default
```

Derived_Y header:

```
struct Derived_Y : public Base<Derived_Y>
{
    explicit Derived_Y() : Base<Derived_Y> { } { }
};

template <>  // Foo specialization for Derived_Y
void Foo<Derived_Y>(Derived_Y* t)
{
    Foo(static_cast<Base<Derived_Y>*>(t));  // <-- call default impl
    TRACE("Derived_Y Foo impl");
}
```

Derived_Z header:

```
template <typename T>
struct Derived_Z : public Base<T>
{
    explicit Derived_Z() : Base<T> { }
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Derived_Z, T>::value, "T must derive from Derived_Z");
    }
};

/*  What does this specialization look like?
template <typename T>
void Foo<Derived_Z<T>>(Derived_Z<T>* t)
{
    Foo(static_cast<Base<T>*>(t));  // <-- call default impl
    TRACE("Derived_Z<T> Foo impl");
}
// */
```

MostDerived Header:

```
struct MostDerived : public Derived_Z<MostDerived>
{
    explicit MostDerived() : Derived_Z<MostDerived> { } { }
};

template <>
void Foo<MostDerived>(MostDerived* t)
{
    Foo(static_cast<Derived_Z<MostDerived>*>(t));  // <-- call Derived_Z impl
    TRACE("MostDerived Foo impl");
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    Derived_X dx { };   // <-- "Default Foo impl"
    Derived_Y dy { };   // <-- "Default Foo impl" && "Derived_Y Foo impl"
    MostDerived md { }; // <-- "Default Foo impl" && "MostDerived Foo impl"
}
```

I have not been able to determine how to specialize `Foo` for `Derived_Z`.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally considered poor form to specialize function templates. You won't be able to partially specialize (as you have noticed), and they won't be considered in overload resolution. Rather, just create overloads, and let overload resolution take care of the rest.

```
// no template at all for Derived_Y
void Foo(Derived_Y* t)
{
    Foo(static_cast<Base<Derived_Y>*>(t));  // <-- call default impl
    TRACE("Derived_Y Foo impl");
}

// a regular template (no specialization) for Derived_Z<T>
template <typename T>
void Foo(Derived_Z<T>* t)
{
    Foo(static_cast<Base<T>*>(t));  // <-- call default impl
    TRACE("Derived_Z<T> Foo impl");
}

// again, no template for MostDerived
void Foo(MostDerived* t)
{
    Foo(static_cast<Derived_Z<MostDerived>*>(t));  // <-- call Derived_Z impl
    TRACE("MostDerived Foo impl");
}
```

Now, you might want to consider changing the base implementation to only accept a `Base<T>*` rather than a `T*`. Say you have `Derived_Y2` that derives from `Derived_Y`, but you have not defined an overload for `Foo(Derived_Y2*)`. Calling `Foo()` using a pointer to a `Derived_Y2` will then go to `Foo(T*)` with `T` being deduced as a `Derived_Y2`, as that is a better match than `Foo(Derived_Y*)`

```
struct Derived_Y2 : Derived_T { };
Derived_Y2 y2; // "Default Foo impl"
```

By changing the base implementation to:

```
template<class T>
void Foo(Base<T>*) { TRACE("Default Foo impl"); }
```

`Foo(Derived_Y*)` will now be a better match when given a pointer to a `Derived_Y2`, because it is *more specialized* as they say.

Comment: That worked great.  So simple - I am a bit embarrassed.  As an added benefit, these functions can be defined as friend functions in different namespaces, and even defined in the target struct itself.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I have not been able to determine how to specialize Foo for Derived_Z.

It's because you can't partial specialize a template function.

But you can partial specialize a `class`/`struct`.

So I propose the use of an helper `struct`

```
template <typename T>
struct bar
 {
   static void func (T *)
    { std::cout << "default bar" << std::endl; }
 };

template <>
struct bar<Derived_Y>
 {
   static void func (Derived_Y *)
    { std::cout << "Derived_Y bar" << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename T>
struct bar<Derived_Z<T>>
 {
   static void func (Derived_Z<T> *)
    { std::cout << "Derived_Z<T> bar" << std::endl; }
 };
```

and `Foo()` simply become

```
template <typename T>
void Foo (T * t)
 { bar<T>::func(t); }
```